# In how many ways can $12$ balls be distributed to $4$ distinguishable bags if the balls are distinguishable and each bag gets at least 3 balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can $12$ balls be distributed to $4$ distinguishable bags if the balls are distinguishable and each bag gets at least 3 balls?

If each bag gets 3 balls then there are 0 balls left. But that will be true if the balls are identical. I am not sure how to do if the balls are nonidentical.

Comment: What do you think? (P.S., this is not a 'do my homework for free' service).

Comment: I think just one 1 way but that would be true of the balls are identical.

Comment: And why do you think that? Can you show this one way and explain why there aren't any others? (within the question please).

Comment: what do you mean? in the question that balls are not identical.

Comment: I have made the title more descriptive.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: can someone help me out??

Comment: The important thing to realize here is that since the balls are distinguishable, we have to choose which balls go into which bag.  Arrange the bags in some order (for instance, by size or color), then choose balls for each bag.  Does this help?

Comment: If the bags AND the balls are all distinct, then all you need to do is to permute the balls in any possible order, i.e., $12!$ different ways of doing it. If the bags are not distinct, then you should divide the previous result by $4!$. If the balls are not distinct, then there is only $1$ way (as you've already noted).

Comment: shouldn't it be P(12,4) because 12! does not take into account that the bags are distinct. it simply arranges the balls.

Comment: @barakmanos  The order of the balls within each bag is not important.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes, but if the bags are distinct, then it's the same as if the order matters (as far as I understand the question). i.e., place the bags in some fixed order, then permute the balls in any order possible.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Oh right, the order of the balls **within each bag** doesn't matter (as shown in your answer, +1).

Comment: so what is the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Since both the balls and the bags are distinguishable, what matters here is which balls are placed in which bag.  Line up the bags in some order (for instance, by size or color).  Choose which three of the $12$ balls go in the first bag, which three of the nine remaining balls go in the second bag, which three of the six remaining balls go in the third bag, and place the rest in the fourth bag.

> $$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$

Comment: so will it be 12 * 9 * 6 * 3 ?
how do i make sure of "which 3 of the balls" ?

Comment: If you scroll over the box, you will see my answer.  Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: yes! it does! thank you!